# Does a Magus/Sorcerer still have to prepare some spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, sorcerer, magus

If I multiclass a Magus and a Sorcerer in Pathfinder, how do my casting mechanics end up? Do I get a certain amount of slots that I must prepare in advance in addition to a few I can improvise with, or do they all become either prepared or improvised? Do my spell lists stay separate for the different slots, or can they cross over between caster lists?

Comment: If you want to play a spontaneous casting magus there is now an archetype for that in the Advanced Class Guide.

Comment: Initially I just wanted that for flavor (Protean heritage + melee and casting synergy), but thanks for bringing that up anyway.

Comment: This question makes me think that they should have included a section in Unchained for multiclassed casters. Perhaps to make it more like 5e...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You retain the casting mechanics of both classes separately.

If you were a [multiclassed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement#TOC-Multiclassing) 4th-level character, for example, a Magus 2/Sorcerer 2, you would have all the class abilities of the level you reached in each class, for instance a 2nd-level Magus and a 2nd-level Sorcerer.  Their spell lists do not mix; you will have to prepare your Magus spells as if a 2nd-level Magus, and your known Sorcerer spells, numbering as many as a 2nd-level Sorcerer would know, can only be cast from the slots that a 2nd-level Sorcerer would have, and would suffer arcane spell failure chance appropriate for the armor you wear.

Comment: Also, you maintain separate caster levels for the two classes.  And of course, this whole system *heavily* discourages playing a PC with multiple casting classes.